# Capturing the content of a html div in a png/jpg image

Tags: javascript, html, forms, image

I'm trying to make a very simple face image generator with html and javascript, where the user would check some checkboxes and add parts of the face to it. The checkboxes are in a form, and I want the user to be able to download a png/jpg image of their creation when they hit the submit button. (or have it automatically get downloaded, doesn't matter). I tried searching for it but I really couldn't find anything besides html2canvas, which I am not allowed to use.

Here's the html code (minimal reproducible version):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body id="pageBody">

  <form action="" id="form">
    <label for="body">Body</label><input type="checkbox" name="body" id="body">
    <label for="eyes">Eyes</label><input type="checkbox" name="eyes" id="eyes">
    <label for="nose">Nose</label><input type="checkbox" name="nose" id="nose">
    <label for="mouth">Mouth</label><input type="checkbox" name="mouth" id="mouth">
    <label for="hat">Hat</label><input type="checkbox" name="hat" id="hat">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
  <br>
  <div id="pic">
    <img id="bodyImg" src="imgs/body.png"/>
    <img id="eyesImg" src="imgs/eyes.png"/>
    <img id="mouthImg" src="imgs/mouth.png"/>
    <img id="noseImg" src="imgs/nose.png"/>
    <img id="hatImg" src="imgs/hat.png"/>
  </div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is the input type file for letting users select images. -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

Comment: @Keith thank you for your comment! unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for, I want the user to be able to get the "pic" div, not upload a file

Comment: Oh, right I think I know what your after now..  I would suggest you make the image an svg, you can then return the svg, or even then convert the svg to png/jpg..

Comment: @Keith I have to use png images for the parts of the image (eyes, nose, etc). Would I be able to convert that to sag?

Comment: Yes,  you can render images to an svg using the image tag  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image, your can then render the svg to canvas if you wanted the user to be able to download a png or jpeg.  If you want the user to download the svg, you would also want to make the images inline using a data-uri..

Comment: @Keith thank you! can you also recommend some documents on how to do the "your can then render the svg to canvas if you wanted the user to be able to download a png or jpeg. If you want the user to download the svg, you would also want to make the images inline using a data-uri" part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you might not need the SVG part, if your just wanting to put together images and then allow the user to save, then you just need Image to Canvas, and then save the canvas.

I've create a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2u0beahf/1) that basically loads 4 images, and then places them side by side on a canvas, that then allows you to download. Unfortunately can't use SO snippets as it too sandboxed for it to work, but fiddle works fine.

```
const svg = document.querySelector('svg');
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function loadImg(src) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const i = new Image();
    i.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
    i.src = src;
    i.onload = () => resolve(i);
    i.onerror = (e) => reject(e);
  });
}

async function doIt() {
  const [i1, i2, i3, i4] = await Promise.all([
    loadImg("https://picsum.photos/id/237/100/150"),
    loadImg("https://picsum.photos/id/238/100/150"),
    loadImg("https://picsum.photos/id/239/100/150"),
    loadImg("https://picsum.photos/id/240/100/150")
  ]);
  ctx.drawImage(i1, 0, 0);
  ctx.drawImage(i2, 100, 0);
  ctx.drawImage(i3, 0, 150);
  ctx.drawImage(i4, 100, 150);
}

function save() {
  const i = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
    .replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
  location.href = i;
}


doIt();
button.addEventListener('click', save)
```